# Disable login after 3 failures, and also to perform email and password validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation, authentication

i created a login page, for performing email and password validation. After email and password validation it should perform login validation (it should disable the input fields for some time after 3 login failures) but here the problem is after a login failure the page gets reload and the attempts are not decreasing.

here is my code,

Thanks in advance....

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Login </title>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var attempt = 3; // Variable to count number of attempts.
// Below function Executes on click of login button.
function validate(){
var username = document.getElementById("jp").value;
var password = document.getElementById("pw").value;
if ( username == "user@gmail.com" && password == "$User123$"){
alert ("Login successfully");
window.location = "success.html"; // Redirecting to other page.
return false;
}
else{
attempt --;// Decrementing by one.
alert("You have left "+attempt+" attempt;");
// Disabling fields after 3 attempts.
if( attempt == 0){
document.getElementById("username").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("password").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
return false;
}
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<br><h1>Login</h1>
Email:
<form>
<input id="jp" type="text" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" required placeholder="Enter you Email">
Password:
<input type="password" id="pw" name="psw" pattern="(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{7,15}$" title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters" required>
<br><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"name="remember"> <font>Remember me</font>
<a href="#" style="margin-left:20px"><font>Forgot password?</font></a><br>
<button type="submit" onclick="validate()" ><b>LOGIN<b></button>
</form>
</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: When you reload a page, you are reloading all your javascript... including your `var attempt = 3;` If you are locking out accounts or disabling the fields after 3 invalid entries, you need to control that server side.

Comment: hi use location storage, maintain flag of invalid login, check each time at header is invalid flag set or not

Comment: @AbhijitJagtap 
LocalStorage wouldn't be suitable as the local storage persists unless you explicitly remove from the browser and that wouldn't be suitable for this case scenario.

Comment: The following functionality should/must be handled at the server side, which @Sean has already suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of mistakes in your code. The most prominent being, you have to use `<form onsubmit="return validate()">` instead of executing the validate function on the click of submit button. I have corrected your complete code and made a pen. Click [here](https://codepen.io/utkarshpramodgupta/pen/OENjJg) to check it.